# GridSearchCV function gives too much warnings

Tags: python, scikit-learn, warnings

I am running `GridSearchCV` function to search for the best `alpha` (coefficient of regularization term) of a Lasso regression model.

When I run the grid search like this,

```
_model = Lasso()
param_dict = {'alpha': [1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1]}
gsearch = GridSearchCV(_model, param_dict, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=5)
```

the same `ConvergenceWarning` appear for about 20 times like below.

```
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:491: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha may cause precision problems.
  ConvergenceWarning)
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:491: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha may cause precision problems.
  ConvergenceWarning)
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:491: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha may cause precision problems.
  ConvergenceWarning)
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:491: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha may cause precision problems.
  ConvergenceWarning)
....
```

The `ConvergenceWarning` is important but when it is displayed so many times like this, it's very annoying.
Is there any other way to display this `ConvergenceWarning` only once?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `warnings` module to deal with it

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("once")
```

The above code will print warnings only once.

You can explore the warnings module [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/warnings.html)

Comment: I added the code you wrote, but it didn't solve the problem.